# pymongo ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: mongodb, flask, docker-compose

I'm doing some tutorial about docker-compose with flask and mongodb. When I run command "docker-compose up", everything is fine. But when I send a post request to insert a json data to database I have Timeout Error like this:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s
```

I guess that I haven't started database yet. But when I try to put command "sudo systemctl stop mongod" in to docker-compose.yml file, I got an error:

```
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 363: exec: sudo: not found
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Post your docker compose YAML.

Comment: The YAML file is fine. Actually, I figured out what I was doing wrong. I used default host and port in client connection. When I change the URI in MongoClient() to 'mongodb://db_container_name' then it solves the problem.